# Error creating IIS WebApplication

Tags: iis, powershell

I added a webApplication Under Default website using powershell as follows:

```
function CreateWebApplication([string]$WebApplicationName,[string]$AppPoolName,[string]$PhysicalPath)
{
    try
    {
    New-WebApplication -Name $WebApplicationName -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath $PhysicalPath  -ApplicationPool $AppPoolName
    Write-Host "Created WebApplication :" $WebApplicationName
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
    write-host $_.Exception.Message `n;
    }
}
```

Its getting created fine,But when i am seeing this in IIS,it has only two section Names IIS and management.but if same thing i do from IIS console,three sections named ASP.net,IIS and management are added.Why i am not getting third section.Another thing if i am trying to enable directory browsing on same,its giving an error that unable to retrieve directory browsing giving some problem with applicationhost.config file.But when i am trying to find applicationhost.config file,its not there in the asked location "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv".What is going wrong here i am not able to fin out.
Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

The application pool is most likely not being created with a `clr` version.

If you open the application pool from `IIS` and look at the `.NET` version it will say

```
No managed code.
```

You can create the app pool and specify the `managedRuntime` version.