# Powershell New-WebApplication successful but asp.net section missing from IIS manager

Tags: iis, powershell

I have created an automatic deployment script using powershell for one of our classic asp applications.

Everything executes correctly and now errors are show and the application is created and show in IIS Manager.

When I carryout the same process manually with IIS Manager the web application show three areas `ASP.NET, IIS and Management`.

The web application create with the powershell script only displays two areas, IIS and Managment.

The script line that I am using to create the web application is

```
$appPool = "Test"

New-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site" -Name "Test" -PhysicalPath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test" -ApplicationPool $appPool
```

The application pool is also newly created before the web application with the follow commands

```
New-Item $appPool
Set-ItemProperty $appPool "managedRuntimeVersion" "v2.0"
Set-ItemProperty $appPool "managedPipelineMode" 1
Set-ItemProperty $appPool -Name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value "True"
```

Which also appears to work correctly.

The application does work correctly in the Web application created by the script.

I did find this question [Error creating IIS WebApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707650/error-creating-iis-webapplication) which details the same problem but I have check the only response to it about having the managed runtime option on the application pool set to none would cause this but it is set to `.Net 2` as show by the script.

Can any one shed any light on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with no asp.net section in IIS when I was creating web applications with Powershell.  In the end I used:

`ConvertTo-WebApplication -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\TESTPARENT\TEST\TEST-1"`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807827.aspx